# ¿Como cambio el texto de mi jlabel de un Jframe segun al boton que presiono desde otro jframe?

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas a todos, quisiera que porfavor alguien me ayude con esto... es algo simple y quiza hasta se rian XD
Pero en fin...
Tengo en un JFrame 5 botones, cada uno contiene de texto una de las 5 vocales... lo que quiero es que cuando presione cualquiera de ellos, se me abra otro JFrame el cual contiene un JLabel, que no tiene ningun texto y quiero asignarle justo el texto(vocal) del boton que presione... alguien me podria ayudar, que es lo que debo saber o implementar para hacer esto??
Lenguaje: Java
IDE: NetBeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al momento de presionar el botón y ejecutar el evento de dicho botón puedes crear el nuevo **JFrame** indicandole el texto al **JLabel**.

Para esto, cada botón debe contar con su propio evento de acción los cuales los agregamos por medio de un **"escuchador de acciones"**, a esto se le llaman **ActionListener**, la clase **JButton* posee el método `addActionListener(...);`.

Cuando creas cada botón, debes asignarle de una vez sus acciones, para esto, supongamos que tienes los 5 botones y que cada uno se llama de acuerdo a su vocal, algo así:

```
private JButton vocalA;
private JButton vocalE;
private JButton vocalI;
private JButton vocalO;
private JButton vocalU;
```

Al momento de instanciarlos, de una vez le agregas sus acciones:

```
vocalA = new JButton("A");
vocalA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Se ejecuta una acción
    }
});
```

Sin embargo, Java ofrece utilizar expresiones Lambda y quedan bastante sencillas:

```
vocalA = new JButton("A");
vocalA.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    // Se ejecuta una acción
});
```

Una vez que cada botón tenga su propia acción (debes hacer eso por cada botón), es momento de llamar al nuevo **JFrame** con el **JLabel** y asignarle la información, para esto, podríamos crear un nuevo método en esta misma clase y como todos los botones van a realizar la misma acción (sólo que cada uno con diferente texto) podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
private void asignarVocal(String vocal){
   // Se realiza la acción
}
```

De esta manera, podrías ahorrar bastante código y simplemente, dentro de cada evento llamas a este método y como parámetro, le pasas el texto que tiene dicho botón por medio de `JButton.getText()`. Nos va quedando algo así:

```
vocalA.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    asignarVocal(vocalA.getText());
});
```

Así, estarías pasándole el nombre del botón (el cuál contiene la letra de la vocal) al método. Ahora solo nos queda asignarle esto al **JLabel**.
Para esto, dentro del método que creamos (*asignarVocal*), haremos algo así:

```
private void asignarVocal(String vocal){
   tuFrame.getTuLabel().setText(vocal);
   tuFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

(Debes cambiar **TuLabel** por el nombre del **JLabel** que está en el otro **JFrame** que creas. Y **tuFrame** por el nombre de tu segundo **JFrame**). De esta manera habrás pasado el texto del botón (el cuál es la letra de la vocal) al **JLabel**.

En resumen, debería quedarnos algo así:

Cuando asignas los botones:

```
private void iniciarComponentes(){ // < esto es a modo de ejemplo, no sé como lo hagas en tu clase
    // Declaras tus variables....

    vocalA.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        asignarVocal(vocalA.getText());
    });
    vocalE.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        asignarVocal(vocalE.getText());
    });
    vocalI.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        asignarVocal(vocalI.getText());
    });
    vocalO.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        asignarVocal(vocalO.getText());
    });
    vocalU.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        asignarVocal(vocalU.getText());
    });

    // Inicias otros componentes...
}

private void asignarVocal(String vocal){
   tuFrame.getTuLabel().setText(vocal);
   tuFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Y con esto bastaría, ¡ahí nos cuentas como te fue!

Comment: Gracias, la verdad a un principio realice directo en el evento del boton las instrucciones que se encuentran dentro de asignarVocal, asi directo, sin crear un metodo, pero igual no me funcionaba... fue extraño, ya en otra me funciono, pero gracias por la respuesta sin duda es mucho mas eficiente y es cierto que si se ahorra el escribir codigo de esta forma... ya todo me funciona perfecto.